# Is there a way to backup my docker environment

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04, docker-machine

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and running some docker containers and images with a python script.Now i have to reinstall that into another Ubuntu machine.

```
Ex: that machine is not even having docker installed
```

Is there a way to backup complete docker engine from my configured machine to another machine

Comment: docker itself is a container why do you want to backup. You must install docker to run images/container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locations to backup vary on how you are running containers and what environment you are restoring to. Some directories to backup include:

- /var/lib/docker: this includes all the images, containers, plugins, and swarm settings
- /etc/docker: this includes any customizations in daemon.json and is commonly used for TLS certificates
- /etc/systemd/system/docker*: you may have customized the startup scripts in this location

What this doesn't include are any container specific host volumes you've mounted to various locations on the host file system. You can look for these directories with:

```
$ docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect -f '{{.Name}}:
{{ range .HostConfig.Binds }}{{.}}
{{end}}
'
```

If you are changing your target server in some way, e.g. changing the kernel running a different version of linux, there's a chance you'll change your storage driver, which will result in your old images and containers becoming inaccessible. In that case, to copy images I'd recommend using a registry server to push your images too and pull them down on the new host. The registry server can be run in a container fairly easily and is the preferred way to move images between hosts. If you cannot use a registry server for some reason, you can use `docker save` on the old host and `docker load` on the new host to save the images to a tar file and import them.

With a platform change, after copying images, you will still need to copy volumes in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` and any other host locations. Then you'll need to copy the container configuration, preferably with a docker-compose.yml, to restart the containers on the new host.

Answer (score 1):

At minimum, you has to install Docker (the same version if possible) on the new Ubuntu machine.

On your original machine, you can gracefully shutdown your containers. Backup `/var/lib/docker` (by default), and then restore on your new machine.

I do this with AWS EC2 spot instance. Not guarantee if this works with different version Docker.